# Can't open a Minecraft server's console on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, session, server, screen, minecraft

So I have a Minecraft server that's running on a vm (of ubuntu). When I want to open the console I usually can just create a screen open the server in it. And open the screen when I needed to access the console.
But if I run the 'restart' command I can't find the server once it's running and I can't connect to it. Any help?

I tried searching for a screen that that runs the server but there are no screens open yet the server is still running.

Answer (score 1):

For minecraft servers running on Linux operating systems we strongly recommend using screen, this option allows you to leave in the background with the possibility of accessing the console without having to be connected continuously. A few basic commands to get you started:

- `screen -R <name>` : Create the screen
- `screen -x <name>` : Access to the screen
- To exit: `CTRL + A + D`
- `screen -ls` : To see the whole list
- `screen -XS <name> kill` : Kill the screen from the outside
- To kill the screen from inside: `CTRL + D`

I hope I could help you, you have a much more extensive tutorial: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

Best regards,
Alex.